# Leaflet - populate circle when clicking on the marker - based on csv data

Tags: leaflet, csv

I've produced Leaflet map based on the CSV data as per the project below:
https://github.com/HandsOnDataViz/leaflet-map-csv
https://handsondataviz.org/leaflet-maps-with-csv.html

It works well, although I am stuck on one functionality. Namely, I would like to have the circle with a radius populated when clicking on the marker.

My code looks like this:

```
 $.get('survey.csv', function(csvString) {
        var data = Papa.parse(csvString, {header: true, dynamicTyping: true}).data;

        for (var i in data) {
            var row = data[i];

            var marker = L.marker([row.lat, row.lng], {
                opacity: 1
            }).bindPopup('<b> Name: </b>' + row.sp + '<br><b> Phone: </b>' + row.phone).on('click', function(e) {
                console.log(data);
            });
            marker.addTo(map).on('click', addCircle).on('popupclose', removeCircle);

            function removeCircle() {
                map.eachLayer(function(layer){
                    if (layer instanceof L.Circle)
                    map.removeLayer(layer)
                });
            }

            function addCircle(e) {
                coords = e.latlng
                var radius = row.radius * 1560
                removeCircle()

                var circle = L.circle([coords.lat,coords.lng]).addTo(map)

                circle.setStyle({
                    color: 'black',
                    fillcolor: 'black'
                })
                circle.setRadius(radius)
            }
        }
    })
```

and it doesn't work, because I am getting an error:

Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, -0.351635159)

at:

```
  circle.setRadius(radius)
```

When the radius is defined as a number, everything is fine. When I try to assign the radius defined in my CSV file under column radius by calling `row.radius`, the error appears.

I tried to define the csv data again within the addCircle(e) function, but it didn't work either. How could I set the csv-based radius on my pop-up circle?

[image]

Comment: What does your csv file look like?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are defining functions `addCircle()` and `removeCircle` again and again in `for (var i in data)` loop within `$.get('survey.csv', function(csvString)` call.

Just move those definition outside:

```
function removeCircle() {
  map.eachLayer(function(layer){
  if (layer instanceof L.Circle)
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  });
}

function addCircle(e, row) {
  var coords = e.latlng
  var radius = row.radius * 1560
  removeCircle();

  var circle = L.circle([coords.lat,coords.lng]).addTo(map);

  circle.setStyle({
    color: 'black',
    fillcolor: 'black'
  });
  circle.setRadius(radius);
}

$.get('survey.csv', function(csvString) {
  var data = Papa.parse(csvString, {header: true, dynamicTyping: true}).data;
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var marker = L.marker([row.lat, row.lng], {
        opacity: 1
    }).bindPopup('<b> Name: </b>' + row.sp + '<br><b> Phone: </b>' + row.phone).on('click', function(e) {
      console.log(data);
    });
    marker.addTo(map).on('click', function(evt) {
      addCircle(evt, row);
    }).on('popupclose', removeCircle);
  }
});
```

Comment: When I move them outside I have the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: row is not defined
they must be inside the csv function

Comment: Yes, I forgot about `row` variable. See modified answer.

Comment: Now the same error as at the very beginning: 
Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, -0.3597904)
but I see that the reason might be at this line: var marker = L.marker([row.lat, row.lng] which throws another error: Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined) despite presence of all markers.

Comment: Without your `survey.csv` file it's hard to say what/where/why it goes wrong.